# The response of the WebApplicationException cannot be utilized as the response is already committed. Re-throwing to the HTTP container

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout, jersey

I have Jersey based REST Resource class with multiple resources that each serves a JSON object. I have a simple HTML+Javascipt interface where data from each REST resource is fetched with a jquery ajax call and the returned JSON is rendered as an ExtJS grid.

Based on what user selects (multiple check boxes), multiple ajax calls are made and success method renders the json into a Grid.

One of the Ajax calls takes around a minute, while others take about 4-10seconds.

Sometimes, I see this "Timeout" error (stacktrace pasted below) on the server side and then Ajax's error method gets called. **This happens only when I am on a wireless network at work, but works fine when I am on a wired connection.**

I have no idea what is going on here:

```
if(//Checkbox-1 is selected){
    $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: 'GET',
             timeout: '120000',
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data){
                 displayExtJsGrid1(data); //this displays the grid 1 in div1 element.
             },
             error: function(){
                 $("#div1").html("Error: Couldn't get results of analysis");
             }
          });
}
if (//checkbox-2 is selected){
    $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: 'GET',                        
             timeout: '120000',
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data){
                 displayExtJsGrid2(data); //this displays the grid 2 in div2 element.
             },                        
             error: function(){
                $("#div2").html("Error: Couldn't get results of analysis");
             }
     });
}
if (//checkbox-3 is selected){
  .....
  .....similar to above call....
}
```

On the server side, my jax-rs (jersey) resources look like this:

```
@GET
@Produces( { "application/json","application/xml"})
@Path("/{data}
public List<Result> getAnalysisOne(@PathParam("data") String data){
    try {           
        //Invokes a DAO class that does some computations

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(
                Status.BAD_REQUEST).type("application/xml").entity(
                "<error>Error</error>").build());
    }
    return results;
}

@GET
@Produces( { "application/json","application/xml"})
@Path("/two/{data}
public List<Result> getAnalysisTwo(@PathParam("data") String data){
    try {           
        //Invokes a DAO class that does some computations

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(
                Status.BAD_REQUEST).type("application/xml").entity(
                "<error>Error</error>").build());
    }
    return results;
}
```

The weird thing is the I get the following error **mostly** when I am on a wireless connection (that isn't very good) and works perfectly fine on Wired connection (all grids get rendered). On the client side, the Ajax's Error method gets invoked when I get this error. Most of the time it is the first ajax call (that takes about a minute to return) that gives the error, while the others succeed and display the grids.

I am using jetty-maven-plugin's mvn jetty:run to start both the Jersey resources and the webapp. I use JAXB for marshaling the data based on the request type (xml or json).

The error on the server side:

```
Oct 17, 2012 12:20:07 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _handleRequest
SEVERE: The response of the WebApplicationException cannot be utilized as the response is already committed. Re-throwing to the HTTP container
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:266)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1451)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider.writeList(JSONListElementProvider.java:145)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:264)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.writer.JsonXmlStreamWriter.writeStartElement(JsonXmlStreamWriter.java:443)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.XMLStreamWriterOutput.beginStartTag(XMLStreamWriterOutput.java:118)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.XmlOutputAbstractImpl.beginStartTag(XmlOutputAbstractImpl.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.NamespaceContextImpl$Element.startElement(NamespaceContextImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.endNamespaceDecls(XMLSerializer.java:291)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:594)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:320)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.AbstractGenerator.blockForOutput(AbstractGenerator.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:107)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.write(WebComponent.java:305)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:134)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:263)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:106)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:116)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:203)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.writer.JsonXmlStreamWriter$WriterAdapter.write(JsonXmlStreamWriter.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.writer.JsonXmlStreamWriter.writeStartElement(JsonXmlStreamWriter.java:438)
    ... 44 more
2012-10-17 00:20:07.352:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/resources/ARX%3ALRP2%3AMED12%3AOFD1%3AZEB2%3AAHI1%3ACREBBP%3AFGFR1%3AFGFR2%3AHESX1%3AKIF7%3APAX6%3AARL13B%3AATRX%3ACC2D2A%3ACEP290%3ADCX%3ANFIB%3ANPHP1%3ANSD1%3ANTN1%3APAFAH1B1%3APEX13%3ARELN%3ATSC1%3ATSC2%3AFOXP2%3AOXTR%3ARELN%3ADLX2%3AFEZF2%3AFEZF2%3APCDH9%3APITX1%3ASLC6A4%3ADAB1%3ADLX1%3AROBO1%3AROBO1%3ADRD1%3ADRD2%3AERBB4%3AGAD1%3ARELN%3ARPGRIP1L%3ARPGRIP1L%3ASLC6A4%3ACCKAR%3AFOXP2%3AGRIN1%3AGSK3B%3ANR4A2%3ANUMBL%3ANUMBL%3ASLC1A2%3AAHI1%3ADPYSL2
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException| - with linked exception:|[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:266)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1451)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: 
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException| - with linked exception:|[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider.writeList(JSONListElementProvider.java:145)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:264)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1451)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: 
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.writer.JsonXmlStreamWriter.writeStartElement(JsonXmlStreamWriter.java:443)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.XMLStreamWriterOutput.beginStartTag(XMLStreamWriterOutput.java:118)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.XmlOutputAbstractImpl.beginStartTag(XmlOutputAbstractImpl.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.NamespaceContextImpl$Element.startElement(NamespaceContextImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.endNamespaceDecls(XMLSerializer.java:291)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:594)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider.writeList(JSONListElementProvider.java:145)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:264)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1451)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: 
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.AbstractGenerator.blockForOutput(AbstractGenerator.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:107)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.write(WebComponent.java:305)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:134)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:263)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:106)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:116)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:203)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.writer.JsonXmlStreamWriter$WriterAdapter.write(JsonXmlStreamWriter.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.writer.JsonXmlStreamWriter.writeStartElement(JsonXmlStreamWriter.java:438)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.XMLStreamWriterOutput.beginStartTag(XMLStreamWriterOutput.java:118)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.XmlOutputAbstractImpl.beginStartTag(XmlOutputAbstractImpl.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.NamespaceContextImpl$Element.startElement(NamespaceContextImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.endNamespaceDecls(XMLSerializer.java:291)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:594)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider.writeList(JSONListElementProvider.java:145)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:264)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1451)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Would appreciate any help/suggestions:

Comment: The problem is not in response already commited, but in org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: timeout. Your connection timed out. So the response was already sent back. So when you have tried to response, the http response was already sent back. Try to change the timeout on your server

Comment: Increasing the maxIdleTime in jetty seem to have solved it. I changed it in the pom.xml configuration:        <maxIdleTime>120000</maxIdleTime>

But another question: Earlier the maxIdleTime was set to "100" and still the ajax calls that returned back in say 10-15secs worked fine. But the ones that were taking about a minutes were giving the timeout error. With maxidletime set to just 100, shouldn't the other ajax calls that returned back in 10secs also fail?

Answer (score 0):

well i think you should add:

`timeout: <number of miliseconds>`,

in `$.ajax({})`.

Also, `cache: false`, can help in a few cases.

[More info](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#toptions)

Comment: I do have a timeout in my ajax call!

Comment: well i think you should increase it

Comment: I have it set for 2mins. The analysis finishes in about 1min. And I see this error before that 2min timeout window.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your server timeout. You are using Jetty server. So look at this post.

[how to set connection/request timeout for jetty server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445006/how-to-set-connection-request-timeout-for-jetty-sever)